# DeploymentProvider in manifest of ClickOnce depends on <Import Project=.. in project file

Tags: build, clickonce, manifest

When I publish my project in VS2010 for ClickOnce a strange value for `<deploymentProvider codebase="file://oldserver/.../....application" />` was present in my manifest file. The name *oldserver* name was wrong, it had to be replaced.

I didn't have a clue where the name *oldserver* came from?
In the project file I had

```
<InstallUrl>\\newserver\...\</InstallUrl>
```

but when opened, in the project properties in VS2010 *oldserver* was again displayed as publish folder location.

SOLUTION: In a hidden file called *buildconfig.targets* this was configured.
This file was referenced in the .proj file:

```
<Import Project="buildconfig.targets" />
```

In this file you need

```
<UpdateUrl>\\newserver\...\</UpdateUrl>
```

as well!

Answer (score 2):

If you're publishing from Visual Studio, make sure you set the Install Url.
It's in the publish settings (in project settings for the project you are publishing) underneath the install url.
If you're publishing from MSBuild, then you need to set the UpdateUrl property (/p:UpdateUrl=youraddress for example).

Comment: rather bizzaro..but sure enough, setting UpdateUrl did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your project in Visual Studio. select Build and then Configuration Manager. Check the information in your build configurations for Debug and Release and make sure they are correct. This is a total guess, but I could see something being set up in there.